# Visual Studio 2017. LNK1104: cannot open file ….\Debug\….exe after single successful build

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, c++-cli

I am having a very weird issue. I am able to build  my C++/CLR Win Forms project with visual studio 2017 only once. Every next time I am getting “LNK1104 cannot open file ….\Debug\….exe” error.

What I have noticed is that after stopping debugging the program is still visible in Task Manager which is I believe the reason of getting the above message.
When I try to kill it am getting “access denied”.

The only way to compile the project is to restart visual studio. The process shuts down immediately together with visual studio.  Once the visual studio is back on I can do a single build again.

I have tried to run "clean" project and solution.
I have also created new project and moved my files in it. What I have noticed is that before having my form filled with controls the problem was not appearing. It started happening after adding few textBoxes, ListView and buttons.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Not weird, it is common.  Uninstall/disable the installed anti-malware product.

Comment: The thing is I have no anti-malware. Visual Studio is running on Win10 virtual machine which has almost nothing else installed. Windows Defender is turned off as well.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was causing the issue. I have tried with switching off multiple Windows security features and finally I found the right one. The problem appeared to be a Windows 10 built in "Real-time protection" against malware. It can be disabled under "Virus & threat protection settings".